# Not able to display ArrayList Values using JSP Expression Language

Tags: jsp, el

I am not able to display values of ArrayList using Expression Language. The following is code snippet I am using 
In Servlet I am using the code and putting the ArrayList in session

```
        List list=new ArrayList();
        list.add("10/3/2013");
        list.add("sample.txt");
        list.add("error at line 45");
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("list",list);
        response.sendRedirect("diaplayDetails.jsp");
```

in displayDetails.jsp Contains the following code

```
         Error File Details Are :
         ${list[0]}
         ${list[1]} 
         ${list[2]}
```

but I am not getting Array list values.

Please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks

Raj

Comment: if you using JDK5 or later , please use the [Generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: What error exactly you are getting ?

Comment: @ ajduke: I am getting no error ,but it is showing empty page

Comment: have you cast it down the `list` object to `List`

Comment: @ajduke: great tip. after casting down to List it is working .. thanks .. but why I am not able to display ArrayList elements but able to display List?

Comment: if you cast it down to `ArrayList` then you can get that `ArrayList`. But dont worry you using the interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast down the `list` object in the JSP to 'List' class 
The reason behind this, in Session object we store the `Object` we require downcast for the accessing the specific object

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSTL try this:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="elem">
    <c:out value="${elem}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to provide scope in EL. Right syntax should look like this:

```
Error File Details Are:
${sessionScope.list[0]}
${sessionScope.list[1]}
${sessionScope.list[2]}
```

sessionScope is one of EL implicit objects. All of those scope implicit objects are used to find in wich scope JSP need to search your atribute key. In your case it is "list". So: `sessionScope`- in wich scope you set your atribute, `list` - a key name of your atribute, `[0]` - index within value part of your atribute.

And remember you using scopes only to get atributes. To parameters you should use `pageContext` or `param` implicit objects.

[More about Expression Language and implicit objects.](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html)